# common elements php html navbar

Tags: php, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make a template for my website.
Basically taking out all the common stuff out using php's include function.

I have made a navigationbar.php and samplepage.php.
navigationbar has all the links to stylesheets etc.
When they are in the same folder and I include navigationbar.php in samplepage it works just fine.

However when i move samplepage.php to a subdirectory (leaving navigationbar.php in the same folder) and 
link navigationbar.php with  the menu doesn't come formatted.
it seems samplepage is getting contents from navigationbar.php but navigationbar is not linking to the css files.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here?
i'm using xampp and have tried with both relative and absolute paths- (include '../navigation.php' and 'localhost/folder/navigation.php')

Answer (score 0):

Make the paths of your css files absolute (i.e. start with `/` and specify the full path).  This will allow them to work correctly from any path.

Answer (score 0):

When including a file in PHP, the url's are relative to the file you are including into. Not to the file you are including.
So you need to change your paths 'navigationbar.php'

Comment: Great thanks! I was wondering about that at first. makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try using something along the lines of this to link to your header/footer files:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path_to/header.php');
```

and then appropriately link to your .js/.css files within header.

Comment: Great to hear. How about clicking that little checkbox to the left... the "accept this answer".

Answer (score 0):

Where your PHP files are has no direct influence. You have to make sure that the resulting HTML has the correct paths to all CSS/JS/img files etc. You may want to post your file structure here and show the code that calls the relevant CSS files.